# Large abstract base classes

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, abstract, radix

I'm writing a large abstract base class with 30 something purely virtual methods*.

Finding all the functions to implement in a base class in the implementation classes is a little tedious, mostly because MSVC++ does not *tell you* which function you failed to implement with compiler error "Cannot construct abstract class"

So, I'm wondering is my large abstract base class a bad idea, or should I split it up into several interfaces, or is there a compiler warning I can activate that'll tell me WHICH method I failed to provide an implementation for.. or is this just a part of coding with abstract classes and I should get used to it.

<sub>*What it does is provide a layer of common functionality between a few different rendering subsystems.</sub>

Comment: My MSVC does tell me which functions are abstract.

Comment: If you can divide up the interface in to clear components, do it.  I won't claim to have a good rational reason for this, but I think it's obviously a good thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no obvious correct answer to this question.  Deciding whether to factor apart the base class into multiple abstract base classes should probably be a decision you make based on whether or not the base class *logically* represents several different concepts, rather than on poor compiler error messages.  If the only reason you'd do this is for the compiler error messages, you might want to check and see if you can upgrade the compiler or if there's some other reason to do this.  Most modern compilers should provide very nice, detailed errors about this.

Splitting the interface into pieces may be a good idea if your design suggests that you might actually want to have multiple different classes that implement just small pieces of the base class.  If you expect to do this, it may be advantageous to factor the interface apart.  You will see some added complexity from this, however.  For example, if you have a pointer of one interface type to an object implementing multiple interfaces, you may have to do some sort of cross-cast to obtain the correct type, or you may have to introduce a new abstract class that represents something inheriting from all the different interface types.  Multiple inheritance with interface classes might also lead to some name collisions, though this typically isn't a problem if the interfaces are designed correctly.

In short, I'd strongly suggest not doing this for the compiler error reason, but if you think it's a good design decision then by all means go for it.  Compilers are good enough these days that you rarely (but not never) need to build your design around them.

Answer (score 4):

Interface classes in my opinion are inherently bad, however the question as posed makes this particular application sound suspect.

If you have classes that are deriving from this interface, and it's not clear exactly what functions you need to override, that seems to indicate that all those functions may not be necessary.

When you craft an abstract base class, the number of pure virtual methods isn't important (to me), but it should be clear why every class that derives from this interface has to implement each pure virtual function.  If you find yourself thinking "Why do I have to implement this function?", it may be appropriate to break the abstract class up into several distinct interfaces.

Comment: The last paragraph really gets to the guts of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway such a big class is a mess, God class antipatern. Use aggregation/composition to split a class and take a look at SOLID development principles, looks like 30 methods for a single class do not follows single responsibility principle, at least... so I wold like recommend to reconsider a design of class. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, right after the error "Cannot instantiate abstract class" (which is thrown at the line it was called), if you copied and pasted the interface into the class before writing the implementations, you'll get a linker error "Unresolved external error"pointing to the method you forgot to implement.